# Identical constraints on identical images, different behaviour?

Tags: ios, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using the same image inside different imageviews, with the same constraints, yet somehow, last 2 images don't keep aspect ratios, despite constraints.

Here's the constraint code.

PS: all of them have the following 2 lines. (I just removed those lines from each group to avoid wall of code).

.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit

.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

```
ImageLineEvents.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: LabelTitleEvents.bottomAnchor, constant:UI_SPACING_SCROLL).isActive = true
ImageLineEvents.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ScrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineEvents.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: VC_UserProfile.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineEvents.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ImageLineEvents.heightAnchor, multiplier: (ImageLineEvents.image?.size.width)! / (ImageLineEvents.image?.size.height)!).isActive = true

ImageLineUpdates.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: LabelTitleUpdates.bottomAnchor, constant:UI_SPACING_SCROLL).isActive = true
ImageLineUpdates.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ScrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineUpdates.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: VC_UserProfile.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineUpdates.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ImageLineUpdates.heightAnchor, multiplier: (ImageLineUpdates.image?.size.width)! / (ImageLineUpdates.image?.size.height)!).isActive = true

ImageLineSoon.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: LabelTitleSoon.bottomAnchor, constant:UI_SPACING_SCROLL).isActive = true
ImageLineSoon.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ScrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineSoon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: VC_UserProfile.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineSoon.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ImageLineSoon.heightAnchor, multiplier: (ImageLineSoon.image?.size.width)! / (ImageLineSoon.image?.size.height)!).isActive = true

ImageLineToday.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: LabelTitleToday.bottomAnchor, constant:UI_SPACING_SCROLL).isActive = true
ImageLineToday.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ScrollView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineToday.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: VC_UserProfile.view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
ImageLineToday.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: ImageLineToday.heightAnchor, multiplier: (ImageLineToday.image?.size.width)! / (ImageLineToday.image?.size.height)!).isActive = true
```

Everything is fine in portait mode, but when I turn to landscape, somehow last 2 images do not keep aspect ratios. I have logs from each orientation.

```
print("ar = \(Float((ImageLineEvents.image?.size.width)!) / Float((ImageLineEvents.image?.size.height)!))")
print("ar = \(Float((ImageLineUpdates.image?.size.width)!) / Float((ImageLineUpdates.image?.size.height)!))")
print("ar = \(Float((ImageLineSoon.image?.size.width)!) / Float((ImageLineSoon.image?.size.height)!))")
print("ar = \(Float((ImageLineToday.image?.size.width)!) / Float((ImageLineToday.image?.size.height)!))")

print("w = \(ImageLineEvents.frame.width)")
print("w = \(ImageLineUpdates.frame.width)")
print("w = \(ImageLineSoon.frame.width)")
print("w = \(ImageLineToday.frame.width)")

print("h = \(ImageLineEvents.frame.height)")
print("h = \(ImageLineUpdates.frame.height)")
print("h = \(ImageLineSoon.frame.height)")
print("h = \(ImageLineToday.frame.height)")
```

These are from portrait and everything is as expected.

ar = 162.5

ar = 162.5

ar = 162.5

ar = 162.5

w = 335.0

w = 335.0

w = 335.0

w = 335.0

h = 2.0

h = 2.0

h = 2.0

h = 2.0

Yet if I turn to landscape, last 2 have different results.

ar = 162.5

ar = 162.5

ar = 162.5

ar = 162.5

w = 684.0

w = 684.0

w = 684.0

w = 684.0

h = 4.33333333333333

h = 4.33333333333333

**h = 4.0 (Why is this not 4.33 ???)**

**h = 4.0 (Why is this not 4.33 ???)**

I looked millions of times but I still can't figure out what's wrong with this. There are no constraint errors. Visually, last 2 images do not go all over the edges, because they keep aspect ratios, yet somehow the height is lower. They are all inside a ScrollView, but I don't see how that can matter. Any help ?

**EDIT:**
I've added the visual result. First 2 constraints are the first image, last 2 are the last image. As you can see, their widths are not the same in landscape. The image in question is the line just below the title and it should spread from title leading to dot image trailing. All of them behave well on portrait, yet on landscape, last 2 behave differently.

**Correct Behaviour**
[image: Correct Behaviour]

**Wrong Behaviour**
[image: Wrong Behaviour]

Comment: Can you please show a picture of how it looks?

Comment: Sure, I will edit the post.

Comment: Done, the imageview in question is the line beneath the text. The line should be as wide as the whole screen (where the text is starting, till where the dot image is ending).

Comment: Why do you have to do this programmatically? Can't you just do it on a xib?

Comment: I really can't, it's a huge app, with dynamic content... Every component is a ViewController, and these lines are just separators between different components. But that's not the point, the point is why is this weird behaviour ? All 4 lines have the same width constraint, yet the last 2 are different and do not keep aspect ratio, despite constraints.

Comment: If this helps anyone, if I change last 2 images top anchor, to be the same as the first one (literally moving them on top of each other) they behave correctly. This is even more mind bogling for me, as to why would a top anchor impact the width anchor and aspect ratio.

Comment: Could you also print the size of your image(s)? I can imagine that some sort of rounding is happening which results in this unpredictable behavior.